# Virtual fibring of $\mathrm{Out}(F_2\times F_2)$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

A finitely generated group $G$ is said to virtually fibre if there is a finite index subgroup $H\leq G$ and a non-trivial map $\varphi:H\to\mathbb{Z}$ with $\ker(\varphi)$ finitely generated.

I want to know whether it is known if $\mathrm{Out}(F_2\times F_2)$ virtually fibres or not. I know that $\mathrm{Out}(F_2\times F_2)$ does not have Kazhdan's property (T) because $\mathrm{Out}(F_2\times F_2)$ is large. This is good becuase  Kazhdan's property (T)  implies not virtually fibred. Hence, I don't see any particular reason which implies that $\mathrm{Out}(F_2\times F_2)$ is not virtually fibred, but I did not find any paper solving this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $G$ is a directly indecomposable group with trivial center, then $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times G)$ contains $\mathrm{Aut}(G)^2$ as subgroup of index 2, and same for Out. And yes, if $G$ is any finitely generated group with a surjective homomorphism to $\mathbf{Z}$, then $G\times G$ has a surjective homomorphism to $\mathbf{Z}$ with finitely generated kernel. Indeed writing $G=N\rtimes_u\mathbf{Z}$, then we can choose this kernel to be $(N\times N)\rtimes_{u,u}\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: By the way, Kazhdan's property is a bit far from this. It already discards the existence of a finite index subgroup surjecting onto $\mathbf{Z}$, regardless of finite generation of the center. That $\mathrm{Out}(F_2\times F_2)$ virtually surjects onto $\mathbf{Z}$ follows from the first third of my previous comment.

Comment: @YCor Thanks!!! Can you provide me a reference for the fact that if $G$ is a directly indecomposable group with trivial center then $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times G)$ contains $\mathrm{Aut}(G)^2$ as a subgroup of index $2$?

Comment: Let $H_1,H_2$ be directly indecomposable groups with trivial center and $G=H_1\times H_2$. I claim that the only subgroups $D$ of $G$ with the property that $G=D\times C(D)$ and $D=C(C(D))$ ($C$ meaning centralizer) are $1$, $G$, $H_1$ and $H_2$. Indeed, being a centralizer, $D=K_1\times K_2$ with $K_i\subset H_i$, so $C(D)=C(K_1)\times C(K_2)$, implying $H_i=K_i\times C(K_i)$. Since $H_i$ is indecomposable, we get $K_i\in\{1,H_i\}$ for $i=1,2$, which provides the 4 possibilities. In particular, the automorphism group exchanges $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Comment: @YCor Maybe I'm missing something. But you were claiming that $\mathrm{Out}(F_2\times F_2)$ virtually fibers? Because $\mathrm{Out}(F_2)\cong GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which is known to have non-zero first $\ell^2$-Betti number. And that is a condition that denies the group from virtually fibre. Hence your argument does not work.

Comment: You're missing something. $\mathrm{Out}(F_2)$ has a nonzero 1st Betti number, but $\mathrm{Out}(F_2)^2$ has a zero 1st Betti number.

Comment: Maybe just to simplify things a little, I think the argument is just that $\mathrm{Out}(F_2 \times F_2)$ is virtually $\mathrm{Out}(F_2) \times \mathrm{Out}(F_2)$, hence is virtually (free-cross-free), hence virtually fibers.

Comment: @MattZaremsky this simplifies only because you take for granted that $F_2\times F_2$ virtually fibers, while I reproved it. Actually the argument shows that if $G,H$ are finitely generated and virtually map onto $\mathbf{Z}$, then $G\times H$ virtually fibers.

Comment: @YCor Oh yeah I didn't really mean a mathematical simplification, more of a "concise-ification" down to one sentence. (I think the fact that free-cross-free fibers counts as "well known", although that is a good point that any (maps onto Z)-cross-(maps onto Z) fibers.)

Comment: @Ycor Ohh thanks, now I got it!! One last question, why $(N\times N)\rtimes_{u,u}\mathbb{Z}$ is finitely generated? It is obvious for the case where $N$ is finitely generated, but if not I dont see why is true (maybe is an standard argument that I'm not seeing) Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Since $N\rtimes \langle u\rangle$ is finitely generated, $N$ is finitely generated as $\langle u\rangle$-group (i.e. group endowed with the action of $\langle u\rangle$). The conclusion easily follows.

Comment: @YCor Oh right, I misunderstood what you said. But then, why can we claim that there exists a map with this kernel?. The obvious map given by the sum of the two maps has a diferent kernel. Right?

Comment: @Marcos it's just the other "obvious" map: difference instead of sum.